# Creating views in as400 db2

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

If I create a view in db2, say something like:

```
select 
  RNN(sometable) as rn, 
  c1,c2,c3 
from sometable 
order by rn desc 
fetch first 100 rows only
```

This would essentially pull the last 100 rows from the table (I use RNN because there's nothing else to base that sort by, sadly. Not by my design). My questions on this are:

- Does this view automatically get updated as sometable gets updated
- Does this view, more specifically, remove non-matching rows. For instance, lets say it pulls the last 100 rows out of a file that has 1000. Some one adds a row, does the row with the lowest RN get removed and the new row added?
- Are there any drawbacks to doing this? For instance, performance when the parent table is updated, etc. Or also, are there any compatibility concerns (if I pick a view name that's unique and unlikely to be used by anything else running on it, is it safe to actually create our own views? Keeping in mind we don't actually maintain the software running on the system itself).

The reason I'm creating this view is because we have to pull some information out of a table with over 30m entries, and no way to really order or index that information (again, not by my design, but the software creators).

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Edit: to clarify I'm not actually in a position to just go test this myself or I would. For one I don't know the implications of creating our own view (hence the last question bullet), and two I'm mostly gathering research to present to my boss.

Edit: actually you know what, I'm not going to ask that second question here because it's a different question. This is not about how to find a unique field or any of that, that was a side note in this question. This was about building a view, any implications it has, and if it would do what I'm after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the ORDER BY nor FETCH FIRST clauses are supported in the definition of the outer fullselect in a view in DB2 for i.

You can however, use a common table expression in currently supported releases of DB2 for i (6.1, 7.1, 7.2).

The following was tested on 7.1:

```
create view myview 
 as ( with tbl as (select RNN(sometable) as rn, 
                          c1,c2,c3 
                          from sometable 
                          order by rn desc 
                          fetch first 100 rows only  
                  )
select * from tbl 
)
```

In answer to the rest of your questions, yes the view is dynamic.  Every time you read from it you'll get the last 100 rows at that point in time.

However note that the use of the RRN function, even without ordering by the results, means you'll be doing a full table scan every time you read those 100 rows.  So performance is probably going to suck.

I find it hard to believe there's nothing you can create an index over and use for ordering.  However, if that's really the case, consider adding a column to suit your needs.  It is relatively easy to add a column to a table in DB2 for i without requiring either the dreaded LVLCHK(*NO) or recompiling existing RPG applications.

Comment: With regard to *full table scan* and thus [most often also] implicitly poorer performance, see the following topics [for content; ignoring the topic *Subject:*]:<br>[link:](http://archive.midrange.com/midrange-l/200807/msg01440.html)<br>[link:](http://archive.midrange.com/rpg400-l/201401/msg00087.html)

Comment: Good info Chuck, I'd forgotten you could now create an index over RRN.

Comment: @Charles Sadly yeah, there isn't much to really index by. One requirement is that I need to be able to select the last (latest) entry of the table. Unfortunately this is not easily possible due to the nature of how the table is structured, there is nothing unique in it (The software just puts stuff in it, not much comes out). The closest thing to uniqueness we could get is two columns: A date in YYYYDDD format, and a time in HHMMSS format. Also, I wasn't aware you were limited on not having order by / fetch in the outer select? I was under the impression that just makes it read-only? Thanks!

Comment: @CRPence Thanks for those, I'll definitely have a look at them!

Comment: Also, it's not possible to add a column to the table. At least, I'm not sure it would be wise. We don't maintain the software generating the table, and updates are performed on it periodically. I would be concerned of it removing our changes or conflicting with their software and updates.

Comment: If there is so little control of the TABLE, then surely there is no way to be sure that the highest RRN are the latest record entries; ensuring that takes great care and caution, which seems from your perspective there is little oversight to be had.  If the [effective] date and time data columns are reflective of when the entries were added, then those can be used irrespective their values effecting a unique key; i.e. order by that descending, and FETCH FIRST just like was proposed with RRN.

Comment: @CRPence The issue is we don't really have control over the table. We technically can do whatever we want to the table, the question we can't answer yet is will those changes carry over an update, or will it mess up their ability to update. The only columns representing dates are a date/time split up into two columns both character types, and a timestamp that drills into the MS - again a char type. We are going to contact the software vendor and ask about our changes and their updates as well. I'm going to update the OP with some info.