# Creating a view with the last of each record based on a unit number in DB2 for IBM i (AS/400)

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

**I undeleted this because, quite frankly, this is a different question. The first question I asked was focused on what the implications, if any, of making a view are, and if it was going to do what I thought it was. This is a specific problem, with one specific table we have.**

This one is kind of hard to explain without an example table. We have a table that handles a list of updates on units with the following columns (examples as I'm not sure how much specific info I can give out, but this should cover the case): (**We are running system i  7.1**)

```
unit#, (this is not an actual number, it's a character column, not all units are numeric)
timestamp,
(other stuff that doesn't matter for this)
```

There are numerous issues with how this table was designed:

- The unit# are NOT unique. In fact, there is no indexes on this table at all. There are no unique columns on this table at all.
- The only column that *might* be considered unique is the timestamp. It's a character-type column that holds a timestamp in the format: 2015-05-05-15.27.30.748000
- The table itself is > 10GB in size with > 35m entries.
- The table is updated anywhere from every 15 minutes to an hour by anywhere from 1 - 400 sources at a time and growing. This, to me, makes the timestamp field less unique as with more units comes a greater chance for duplicates. So far there are none, but it doesn't appear that the first 20m rows even have this filled in, so I'm guessing it was a later addition by the software creators.

One of the issues is the fact that we have no control over the software code, and we do not maintain the software itself. Therefore we do not feel comfortable adding new columns (eg: Some column for a unique-per-row indexed column) to the database when that column might be removed or conflicted with when they do an update.

We need all of the rows in this table (Though I am going to inquire as to the possibilities of us doing a dump and backup of it somewhere else, maybe another table that it rolls entries into after they are so old.)

Now, what I need to do is to be able to create a view which goes in here, grabs the latest row for each unit. So for instance:

(for keeping it simple I'm making the timestamps just a number starting at 100)

U1, 100

U3, 103

U1, 105

U2, 110

U4, 111

U1, 115

I would need the view to contain:

U3, 103

U2, 110

U4, 111

U1, 115

And remove previous entries each go (so if U4 gets updated to 118, that u4,111 would be gone)

I'm not intending this to sound like a "Hey do this for me" but I've been at it for about a day-and-a-half trying various things and reading various posts/blogs/docs. If you have a direction for me to look in, feel free to link that I would be more than happy to research from a start!

Thanks, hopefully I explained this (to me at this point) convoluted system lol.

Edit: fixed formatted on the example contents.
Edit: Also any rows without timestamps can just be ignored.

Comment: Rather than asking new questions, consider updating your original question with the expanded info and examples...

Comment: What System i version are you at? How do you want to treat the rows that don't have a timestamp?

Comment: @Charles: I thought about doing that, but I actually considered it to be two different questions. The other one I was intending to be more of a general question about views, this is more specific. Do you still think it should be? (I'm not opposed, not intending to make duplicates.) Would you mind clarifying why or removing your downvote...?

Comment: @mustaccio I'm afraid I don't know off hand, I'm trying to find out atm. Also the rows that don't have a timestamp can be safely ignored. They are all well before anything I need.

Comment: @Charles I updated this OP, because this is a different question. I would appreciate it if you read the heading and removed your downvote.

Comment: @ThomasF. If you find answer that leads you to a solution, mark it as such (see mustaccio's answer). Waiting for an answer that satisfies your problem AND is fast enough in your opinion is not in the spirit of this community.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to figure out what to do with those NULL timestamp values, otherwise the answer might look something like

```
create view v1 as
select unit#, ts from (
  select unit#, ts, row_number() over (partition by unit# order by ts desc) rn
) t where rn = 1
```

I don't have access to System i so I could not test it but it's pretty straightforward SQL so I think it should work.

Comment: Apologies, I've been out sick and just got back in today. This works, and we can disregard nulls (in this case they are really out of date for our purpose anyway.) The issue is, and mostly why I made the question, is the fact that sorting this table is extremely slow due to it's size and lack of any indexes or anything that can be sorted by fast (ts is a string, and thus the sorting is a string comparison and slow - for instance). I'm looking into more options though still, however thanks. This was informative.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I missed this one; I'd responded to the other. Anyhow, noticing this one had no accepted answer, I figured I would reply with what is hopefully a means to get the data quickly and easily given the OP was looking for "more options" and the apparently [still] "slow" results.

Using the [old-fashioned] MAX aggregate should be just as good as an OLAP query for the purposes of the OP. Or perhaps that is even better, given OLAP queries will tend toward [or even require] a temporary result such that the expressed data-change results would not be as dynamic as might be expected; i.e. difficult to know what was implied, as to how dynamic of an effect is required, according to the expressed as desired effect of "*remove previous entries*" for the values that are no longer the *largest* or *most recent* entry according to the TIMESTAMP-like column(s).

The keyed Access Path (ACCPTH) created by the following CREATE INDEX [when used for such a large amount of data as described in the OP] will enable somewhat *quick* access to the data accessed by a query of the VIEW created by the following CREATE VIEW.  This is accomplished by having eliminated all of the blank *timestamp* values with key-selection in the INDEX and having enabled query implementation by the *index-only* access to the data; again, the query should be of the VIEW shown created after that INDEX, because that ensures the consistency of the encapsulated query with the selective INDEX.  Note: The lack of DDL for the *timestamp*, and the description from a prior topic [Creating views in as400 db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054406/creating-views-in-as400-db2) that implied the timestamp data was actually stored in two columns, and that reference to the term NULL in an answer was commented-on without any correction/suggesting otherwise, means that *assumptions* made in this post may not be correct, so adjustments may be necessary -- such is the difficulty, when an OP does not provide actual DDL:

```
create index so30061994_xut 
 on SO30061994 ( unit#, ts )
where ts <> '' /* OP says that *blank* records unneeded */
;
create view so30061994_grp as 
select unit#, max( ts ) as ts
from        so30061994
/* create table so30061994 ( unit# char(x), ts char(26) ) */
where ts <> '' /* must match the predicate in the INDEX   */
group by unit# 
;
select *
from so30061994_grp 
where unit# between 'U1' and 'U4' 
; -- likeness of report from above query
U1          115
U2          110
U3          103
U4          111
```